# Error when building to Android in Unity

Tags: c#, android, unity-game-engine

I have my SDK and JDK set in my preferences, I have the following errors each time I try to run it. Really not sure what the issue is. I have debugging enabled on my phone as well.

> Assets/Vuforia/Scripts/Utilities/VRIntegrationHelper.cs(99,29): error CS1061: Type `UnityEngine.Camera' does not contain a definition for`SetStereoProjectionMatrices' and no extension method `SetStereoProjectionMatrices' of type`UnityEngine.Camera' could be found. Are you missing an assembly reference?

Error building Player because scripts had compiler errors

Build completed with a result of 'Failed'

```
UnityEngine.GUIUtility:ProcessEvent(Int32, IntPtr)

UnityEditor.BuildPlayerWindow+BuildMethodException: 3 errors
at UnityEditor.BuildPlayerWindow+DefaultBuildMethods.BuildPlayer (BuildPlayerOptions options) [0x0021f] in /Users/builduser/buildslave/unity/build/Editor/Mono/BuildPlayerWindowBuildMethods.cs:182 
at UnityEditor.BuildPlayerWindow.CallBuildMethods (Boolean askForBuildLocation, BuildOptions defaultBuildOptions) [0x00065] in /Users/builduser/buildslave/unity/build/Editor/Mono/BuildPlayerWindowBuildMethods.cs:89 
UnityEngine.GUIUtility:ProcessEvent(Int32, IntPtr)
```

[image]

[image]

Comment: Does it run on any other platform? What unity version are you using?

Comment: this is not an OS error, you are missing some scripts or references from Vuforia assets

Comment: I believe SetStereoProjectionMatrices is obsolete in latest unity versions (https://docs.unity3d.com/ScriptReference/Camera.SetStereoProjectionMatrices.html) and most likely Vuforia code isnt updated accordingly.. but its hard to say to 100% without knowing what unity version ur using :)

Comment: I'm using version 2018.1.6f1 Personal

Comment: There you have it then, either look for an updated version of vuforia that works with 2018.1.6f1, or downgrade unity, OR just see if you can fix the vuforia source yourself :)

Answer (score 2):

You need to change the code:

```
mLeftCamera.SetStereoProjectionMatrices(mLeftCamera.projectionMatrix, mRightCamera.projectionMatrix);
mRightCamera.SetStereoProjectionMatrices (mLeftCamera.projectionMatrix, mRightCamera.projectionMatrix);
```

On that:

```
mLeftCamera.SetStereoProjectionMatrix (Camera.StereoscopicEye.Left, mRightCamera.projectionMatrix);
mRightCamera.SetStereoProjectionMatrix (Camera.StereoscopicEye.Right, mRightCamera.projectionMatrix);
```

Comment: I hate to rehash old stuff and I appreciate the quick fix, but the first line is not quite correct and references the wrong camera. It should use `mLeftCamera.projectionMatrix` instead.